# What complex analysis must I know to understand D.J. Newman's proof of the Prime Number Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, prime-numbers, book-recommendation

The title sums it up, but let me flesh out my question. First off, I am referring to a simplification of Newman's proof given by Zagier ([link](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf)), and expanded for clarity [here](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~mbaker/pdf/pnt2.pdf). Now, I am fairly comfortable with calculus, real analysis, and some number theory. However, I have never studied complex analysis (though I understand some basics of complex variables/functions, as I have read the relevant chapters in Spivak's calculus book). What I would like, is to know precisely which topics of complex analysis I need to cover to be able to understand the aforementioned proof; even better, a recommendation of a book (or books) and which chapters are essential to understand the proof argument would be excellent.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know about residues and analytic continuation applied to the zeta function.

The book [Complex Variables](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/CV.html) by Ash and Novinger ends with an exposition of a proof of the Prime Number Theorem along the lines you want:

> Our approach to the prime number theorem has been along traditional lines, but at this stage we will apply D.J. Newman’s method [...] as modified by J. Korevaar. (section 7.3)

There is also the exposition at end of [Complex Analysis](https://www.springer.com/br/book/9781441972873) by Bak and Newman. Yes, that Newman.

Comment: thanks for the sources. as you note, the PNT proof is at the *end* of both books. do you think it necessary to read all or most of the book(s) to understand the proof? if not, and if its not too much trouble, can you recommend which chapters are necessary?

Comment: @Coffee_Table I'd say the main step is to understand that the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)$ is a contour integral where shifting the integration curve to the left means adding a few residues when $ F(s)$ is meromorphic with not too many poles and $|F(\sigma+it)|$ is bounded by a "not too bad" function of $t$.

Comment: @reuns what is $F(s)$, an arbitrary complex function?